# Biblical basis of exaltation (LDS)

Tags: biblical-basis, lds

In regards to this [answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/83947/22319) on LDS biblical contradictions.

Are there biblical scriptures to support the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints belief in [exaltation](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/gospel-principles/chapter-47-exaltation?lang=eng) (progression to godhood) of God, Jesus, or mankind?

Comment: The first two paragraphs of the linked document bear no relation to the biblical scriptures that I can personally decipher(Genesis to Revelation). In particular 'When we lived with our Heavenly Father' and 'telestial kingdom' (sic). Nor has the answer provided any explanation for these two particulars _in regard to quotation from the biblical scripture_. It appears to me (just from this question and answer) that ancillary documentation is required to support these two particular statements.

Comment: The linked document is more to explain the LDS belief for those unfamiliar, as it is the question, ie man progressing to godhood. Exaltation is more complex of a belief then it is often stated by those not of the LDS faith, so I linked to state what the exact belief is. If you would like to ask another question more scriptures could be provided in regards to those aspects (pre-existence/pre-mortality and kingdoms of heaven). Yes other document is required to fully support these statements but there are biblical scriptures

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to remind those not familiar with the LDS faith that their [scriptures](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/gospel-topics/scriptures?lang=eng) includes more than the Bible, including the Book of Mormon, Doctrine and Covenants, and Pearl of Great Price (I will still stay in the Bible, as there are scriptures but this will only be a partial picture of the LDS belief). In addition to this they believe in [prophets](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/gospel-topics/prophets?lang=eng) who are inspired men called to speak for the Lord. These scriptures will not give a full picture of the LDS belief.

[Exaltation](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/gospel-principles/chapter-47-exaltation?lang=eng)

- Only ever 1 God for mankind (becoming a god does not replace or reduce God)

  - [1 Cor 8:5-6](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/nt/1-cor/8.5-6?lang=eng#p5?lang=eng)

  > 5 For though there be that are called gods, whether in heaven or in earth, (as there be gods many, and lords many,)

  > 6 **But to us there is but one God, the Father,** of whom are all things, and we in him; and one Lord Jesus Christ, by whom are all things, and we by him.

  - [Proverbs 17:6](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/ot/prov/17.6#p6?lang=eng)

  > 6 **Children’s children are the crown of old men; and the glory of children are their fathers.**

[God](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/gospel-topics/god-the-father?lang=eng)

- has a body

  - Genesis 1:26-27

  > 26 And **God said, Let us make man in our image, after our likeness:** and let them have dominion over the fish of the sea, and over the fowl of the air, and over the cattle, and over all the earth, and over every creeping thing that creepeth upon the earth.

  > 27 So **God created man in his own image, in the image of God created he him; male and female created he them.**

  - [Genesis 3:8](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/ot/gen/3.8?lang=eng#p8)
  - [Exodus 31:18](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/ot/ex/31.18?lang=eng#p18?lang=eng)

  > 18 And he gave unto Moses, when he had made an end of communing with him upon mount Sinai, two tables of testimony, tables of stone, written with the **finger of God.**

  - [1 John 3:2](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/nt/1-jn/3.2?lang=eng)

[Jesus Christ](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/gospel-topics/jesus-christ?lang=eng)

- [John 10:28-35](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/nt/john/10.28-35?lang=eng#p28) (also mankind)

> 28 And **I give unto them eternal life;** and they shall never perish, neither shall any man pluck them out of my hand.

> 29 **My Father**, which gave them me, is greater than all; and no man is able to pluck them out of my Father’s hand.

> 30 I and my Father are one.

> 31 Then the Jews took up stones again to stone him.

> 32 Jesus answered them, Many good works have I shewed you from my Father; for which of those works do ye stone me?

> 33 The Jews answered him, saying, For a good work we stone thee not; but for blasphemy; and because that thou, being a man, makest thyself God.

> 34 Jesus answered them, Is it not written in your law, I said, **Ye are gods?**

> 35 **If he called them gods, unto whom the word of God came, and the scripture cannot be broken;**

Mankind

- [Psalm 82:6](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/ot/ps/82.6?lang=eng)

> 6 I have said, **Ye are gods; and all of you are children of the most High.**

- [Romans 8:14-18](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/nt/rom/8.14-18?lang=eng#p14?lang=eng) (also Christ)

> 14 For as many as are led by the Spirit of God, they are the **sons of God.**

> 15 For ye have not received the spirit of bondage again to fear; but ye have received the Spirit of adoption, whereby we cry, Abba, Father.

> 16 The Spirit itself beareth witness with our spirit, that **we are the children of God:**

> 17 And **if children, then heirs; heirs of God, and joint-heirs with Christ;** if so be that we suffer with him, that we may be also glorified together.

> 18 For I reckon that the sufferings of this present time are not worthy to be compared with the glory which shall be revealed in us.

- [Romans 4:1-7](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/nt/gal/4.1-7?lang=eng) (also Jesus)

> 1 Now I say, **That the heir, as long as he is a child, differeth nothing from a servant, though he be lord of all;**

> 2 But is under tutors and governors until the time appointed of the father.

> 3 Even so we, when we were children, were in bondage under the elements of the world:

> 4 But when the fulness of the time was come, God sent forth his Son, made of a woman, made under the law,

> 5 To redeem them that were under the law, that we might receive the adoption of sons.

> 6 And **because ye are sons,** God hath sent forth the Spirit of his Son into your hearts, crying, Abba, Father.

> 7 Wherefore thou art no more a servant, **but a son; and if a son, then an heir of God through Christ.**

- [1 John 3:1-3](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/nt/1-jn/3.1-3)

> 1 Behold, what manner of love **the Father hath bestowed upon us, that we should be called the sons of God:** therefore the world knoweth us not, because it knew him not.

> 2 Beloved, now are **we the sons of God**, and it doth not yet appear what we shall be: but **we know that, when he shall appear, we shall be like him; for we shall see him as he is.**

> 3 And every man that hath this hope in him purifieth himself, even as he is pure.

**Opinion** Explanation/logic from these scriptures alone: As we are made in God's image, He has a body, we refer to him as the Father, we are here on earth, and can eventually become gods it can be theorized that he also went through a similar process. He went through this process (man->God) before us but is now God; and just like one's worldly father was once a child and now is an adult(child->Father) when looking at pictures of them as a child you know that that is your father (even if they weren't then)

Other LDS resources on exaltation:

- [King Follett](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/history/topics/king-follett-discourse?lang=eng) discourse
- [Becoming Like God](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/gospel-topics-essays/becoming-like-god?lang=eng)

<sub>All emphasis added by me</sub>

Comment: 1 Cor. 8:6 - One God, the Father, of whom are **all** things and one Lord, Jesus Christ by whom are **all** things.  Apart from them **nothing** was created that has been created.  According to LDS where did God become God prior to **anything** being created?